# How to save user query terms from a search navbar in database that can be acessed after user sessions?

Tags: django, django-sessions

I have a search navbar and I want to save search queries so I can improve the navbar and the autocomplete api, but I'm not sure how. sessions variables seem to only work when user is online and it's difficult to save many users. Should I create my own user model and then write data to it. Can you give me a simple example of how to do this?

I've tried using sessions.request to save variables and then access them after a session and have been unable.

Answer (score 0):

You question is a bit unclear but why not create a table for search terms and foreign key to user model if that's what you need. For example:

```
class SearchTerm(models.Model):
    keywords = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Naturally, this will work for logged in users only where you can do something like this in your view:

```
def search(request):
    keywords = request.get('keywords')
    user = request.user
    st, created = SearchTerm.objects.get_or_create(keywords=keywords, user=user)
```

Look, this is a very simplistic example to illustrate what I think you want to do, but I'm not sure if I have fully understood your question.